# How to redirect/pipe stdout to ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to redirect some output to Ruby script,

so that I can do something on the `output` in Ruby.

for example, "git log | ruby my_script.rb"

Then I can manipulate the output of `git log` in my ruby script.

```
stdout_output = $stdout
stdout_output.each {~~~}
```

The stdout may look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gets` to read input from STDIN, so if your script looks like this:

```
# my_script.rb    
p gets
```

And you run:

```
echo 'Hello World!' | ruby my_script.rb
```

Your STDOUT (console) will output `Hello World!`

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, but I got error `SyntaxError: unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input` the output has ansi-color code

Comment: Can you provide some sample output, and whatever manipulations you do in the script?